# Usage of CJK font in PDFsharp / Telerik RadPdfViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, pdfsharp, cjk

### Some background:

I’m developing a WPF application used for measuring and comparing data that’s delivered of a balance attached to it. It will be installed on a Windows 10 system delivered together with the balance. The application currently has to support eleven languages including Japanese and Chinese. One feature of the application is, that the values measured can be shown as a PDF report. For the creation of the PDF we use the PDFsharp library, for displaying the Telerik RadPdfViewer.
As mentioned before the application supports Japanese and Chinese language, therefore the PDF also needs the ability to show Japanese and Chinese letters. Earlier versions of the application were delivered on older versions of Windows, which meant we could use either the Microsoft YaHei or Arial Unicode MS font for this case. Unfortunately PDFsharp does not support TrueType font collections, which means I can’t use the version of Microsoft Yahei installed on the System and Arial Unicode MS is not available anymore.

### Problem:

Since these two aren’t an option anymore I searched the internet for an alternative. After a quick search I noticed that Google’s Noto Sans might be what I need, so I tried to use it. Unfortunately it resulted in a ton of IndexOutOfRange Exceptions from the Telerik.Windows.Documents.Fixed.dll (all internally caught by the library) and does not show any letters on the generated PDF. It shows the PDF and the lines of the generated table, so I assume it’s some problem with the font. I used “Noto Sans CJK SC Regular” for Chinese and “Noto Sans CJK JP Regular” for Japanese. 
After a long search session I still did not find another suitable font for Chinese. For Japanese I could use “Gen Shin Gothic”, but I’d prefer to use a font with the same style for both languages. There is the additional problem that the font should be usable without an additional license needed.

*Unfortunately I can’t add code, since it’s a running project of my employer.*

### Questions:

- Is there something I need to set/adjust for the Noto fonts to work properly?
- Is there another usable sans-serif font for Chinese, where no additional licensing is needed? (It has to be capable of showing Latin letters too, since some stuff, like the product name is written that way)

### Alternatively:

- Is there a tweak to the PDFsharp library, so it can use TTC fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user posted their changes for TTC support on the PDFsharp forum:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9039#p9039

Another user found a suitable TTF file that works with PDFsharp:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=11874#p11874

> There is one TTF and its font name is "標楷體".